# Woocommerce custom category search

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the code below to search in woocommerce products and i want to be able to search by category in woocommerce. 
if i disable the category section, everything is ok but if  enable it, nothing will be found.
Could you help me find my mistake ?

```
<?php
    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'category_name' => $_GET['category'],
    );

    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>
<?php if ( $wc_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
    <?php while ( $wc_query->have_posts() ) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
<?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: does it show no product found when you remove  `'category_name' => $_GET['category']` from  `$params` array ?

Comment: then will show all products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `'category_name' => $_GET['category'],` to `'product_cat' => $_GET['category'],`

```
<?php
   $params = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 12,
          'post_type' => 'product',
          'product_cat' => $_GET['category'],
          's' => $_GET['s_query'] // search text
       );
      // and so on...
     ?>
```

Try it... It should work !

Comment: what about $s Variable ? should I take any field for that ?

Comment: You can simply pass search string `'s' => $_GET['s_query']` to $param array,,  please check edited code .